# FileMaker 17 Sub-summary value

Tags: sql, filemaker

Edited:

Let me try to explain more clearly. I wrote the earlier message in haste:

I have a sub-summary part which is sorted by the parent table's ID field. In this part, i have placed a summary field from the child table ( on which the layout is based ). This summary field is a running total of a number field in the child table , with restart checked. When this field is placed in the sub-summary part, it summarizes the values of all the records below it. Which is fine. What i want is to show that summarized value in each of the records just below the sub-summary. So for instance if the summary field shows a total of 1,000, then i want to show that 1,000 in each child record below in the layout. Then when the next break occurs and the field summarizes the next set of child records in the sub-summary I also want it to show the same value in the next set of records below it. I hope it's a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand what your question is. Some statements do not make sense at all. A sub-summary part is based on a field, not on a table. And a summary field is not "sorted".

If you want to show a running total in the body, without restarting at each break, you must define your summary field so. A summary field does not have to restart in order to show sub-summary values when placed in a sub-summary part.

---

**Added:**

A summary field displays the sub-summary value only when it's placed in a sub-summary part. If you want to show the same value elsewhere - or use it in a calculation, you must use the [GetSummary()](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/17/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fgetsummary.html%23) function.

Note that the GetSummary() function will only work if the *break field* is a local field. If you're grouping by parent, make sure you're using the foreign key field in the child table - not the primary key field in the parent table.

Comment: Sorry let me try again.

Comment: See the addition to my post. -- P.S. I recommend you join one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform where these questions are more suitable.